# Jquery div background image cycle

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

Any idea why this code is broken or not working? It is not my code but it does appear to be correct, of course I could be missing the obvious. I simply need the background image of a div to cycle to a new one in the/a array ever 5 seconds.

```
var imageIndex = 0;
var imagesArray = new Array();

//Set Images
imagesArray[0] = "images/self-whitewater.png";
imagesArray[1] = "images/fishing.png";
imagesArray[2] = "images/solo-kayaking.png";

function changeBackground(){
$("main-blocki").css("background","url('"+ imagesArray[imageIndex] +"')");                        
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex > imageArray.length)
        imageIndex = 0; 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval("changeBackground()",5000);
});
```

Comment: Not the issue, but you're eval'ing in the interval, remove the quotes and the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in your `if` statement, as specified by @thatidiotguy.

But you could also do this in a oneliner, without the `if` statement.

```
var imageIndex = 0;
var imagesArray = [
    "images/self-whitewater.png",
    "images/fishing.png",
    "images/solo-kayaking.png"
];

function changeBackground(){
    var index = imageIndex++ % imagesArray.length;
    $("main-blocki").css("background","url('"+ imagesArray[index] +"')");      
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(changeBackground, 5000);
});
```

Notice the `imageIndex++ % imagesArray.length`. This increments the global `imageIndex` while making sure that the value is not greater than the `imagesArray.length`.

Comment: This worked properly, Thank you @JAM - I did have an additional error that was breaking the code though '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'  I'm so used to adding the type declaration i didn't realize it was wrong and was breaking the jquery functionality.

Comment: Glad to help @Swodahs :) Sidenote: [you shouldn't be linking the source directly from cody.jquery.com](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/), you should use `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>` instead :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error here:

```
if (imageIndex > imageArray.length)
        imageIndex = 0;
```

There is no variable called `imageArray`

You should use a web debugger to show you when you have syntax errors. One syntax error and Javascript has the grace to kill every other script you are running or trying to run.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (imageIndex > imageArray.length)
```

The above line is wrong : you shall want to test *imagesArray.length* instead

... and you shall test with >= operator also since indexes are 0 based

Comment: Another point is that, even if you use imagesArray.length, this won't work, as imageIndex will never be larger than imagesArray.length.  imagesArray.length will be 3 in this case, but imageIndex will never get to 3.

Comment: @MatRichardson - Uhm, why not ?

Comment: imagesArray.length is 3, right?  Well, the imageindex array only ever gets to 2.  When it reaches 3 there will be no item in the array...

Comment: @MatRichardson The whole point of the if statement is to reset the value when it gets too high. Look at the code one more time.

Comment: Yes, I know, but at some point the value will reach 3, which, in the if statement will cause the value to remain at 3 (3 !> 3)...or am I missing something?

Comment: "... and you shall test with >= operator also since indexes are 0 based" - this was my point before it was added to the answer.

Comment: @MatRichardson - imageIndex is a number that gets incremented until it's more than the number of items in the array, when it's more, it's reset to zero again, so of course it will be more than 2 ?

Comment: What I meant was that there won't be an item in imageArray for imageindex when it reaches 3 in this code.  Didn't explain myself correctly.

Comment: There sure will, the incrementing happens before the if condition and after the array is accessed with the previous index.

Comment: So, at some point, the imageIndex will be incremented to 3, then the test (imageIndex > imagesArray.length) will return false (3 !> 3) and the next time the function runs it will try to access imagesArray(3), which doesn't exist...